# performance optimizing critical code in iOS app

Tags: ios, c, performance, optimization, neon

I am trying to optimize the performance of a critical part of my app. Written in C, the code loops through all pixels of sourceImage and calculates the "color distance" to each of its neighbors, deciding if to record a value derived from colorDistance, before moving on to the next neighbor.

Instrumenting the app in XCode revealed that 70% of the time was spent on what appears to be a simple float calculation—seven times longer than a code line that has three powf and one sqrtf (the calculation of colorDistance consuming 10.8%).

On the left of some code lines below you will see the percentage time spent as it was copied from XCode Instruments. (I also noticed other mundane code lines that surprisingly had a relatively high percentage, even though not close to those I've mentioned above).

Any tips on where and how to optimize would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

```
     for (int row = 1; row < height - 1; row++)
        {            
            for (int col = 1; col < width - 1; col++)
            {
                int pixelIndex = (col + row * width);
1.7%            int pixelIndexIntoImage = pixelIndex * COMPONENTS_PER_PIXEL;

                // loop over pixel's 8 neighbours clockwise starting from neighbor id 0
                // using Nx[] and Ny[] as guides to calculate neighbour locations
1.6%            for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++)
                {
5.3%                int neighborIndex = pixelIndex + Nx[n] + width * Ny[n];
                    int neighborIndexIntoImage = neighborIndex * COMPONENTS_PER_PIXEL;


                    // skip neighbors that are not a foreground or background
3.3%                uint8_t labelValue = labelsMap[neighborIndex];
1.1%                if (labelValue == LABEL_UNKNOWN_VALUE)
                        continue; 



                    // "color distance" between the pixel and the current neighbour
                    float colorDistance;

1.4%                if(numColorComponents == 3)
                    {
5.3%                    uint8_t redPixel = sourceImage[pixelIndexIntoImage  ];
                        uint8_t grnPixel = sourceImage[pixelIndexIntoImage+1];
                        uint8_t bluPixel = sourceImage[pixelIndexIntoImage+2];

                        uint8_t redNeigh = sourceImage[neighborIndexIntoImage  ];
                        uint8_t grnNeigh = sourceImage[neighborIndexIntoImage+1];
                        uint8_t bluNeigh = sourceImage[neighborIndexIntoImage+2];

10.8%                   colorDistance = sqrtf( powf(redPixel-redNeigh, 2) + 
                                               powf(grnPixel-grnNeigh, 2) + 
                                               powf(bluPixel-bluNeigh, 2));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        uint8_t pixel = sourceImage[pixelIndexIntoImage   ];
                        uint8_t neigh = sourceImage[neighborIndexIntoImage];

                        colorDistance = fabsf(pixel - neigh); 
                    }

71.2%               float attackForce = 1.0 - (colorDistance / MAX_COLOR_DISTANCE);

                    if (attackForce * strengthMap[neighborIndex] > revisedStrengthMap[pixelIndex])
                    {
                        //attack succeeds

                        strengthMap[pixelIndex] = attackForce * revisedStrengthMap[neighborIndex];

                        outputMask[pixelIndex] = labelsMap[neighborIndex];

                        isConverged = false; // keep iterating

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Definition of variables

```
uint8_t *sourceImage; // 4 bytes per pixel
uint8_t *labelsMap, *outputMask; // 1 byte per pixel
int     numPixels = width * height;
float   *strengthMap        = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*numPixels);
float   *revisedStrengthMap = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*numPixels);
short   Nx[] = {-1,  0,  1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1}; 
short   Ny[] = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1,  1,  0};
```

Following advise I received (multiplication is "cheaper" than division), I revised one code line, and interestingly enough, 71.2% dropped to 1.7%, BUT the "if" statement just below shot up to 64.8% — i just don't get it!

```
1.7%               float attackForce = 1.0 - (colorDistance * MAX_COLOR_DISTANCE_INV);

64.8%              if (attackForce * strengthMap[neighborIndex] > revisedStrengthMap[pixelIndex])
```

Comment: My understanding is that division is expensive.  If the factor is relatively constant, you can multiply by the reciprocal instead. Also, Instead of powf(x,2), why not use x*x? Although the compiler might figure this out for you.

Comment: Turn the division into multiplication. Ny could be an array of int containing 'width' already multiplied in it.

Comment: Avoid conditionals in your inner loops. I think it doesn't matter as much on ARM however.

Comment: A few more questions - are you compiling fully optimized here?  If not, your numbers are garbage and should be re-collected.  If so, then post the assembler for the above function and we can look deeper into why it is going so slow.

Comment: you could use a small lookup table for the offsets into the neighboring pixels as well.. `{ -(width+1), -width, -(width-1), -1, 1, +(width-1), +width, +(width+1) }`

Comment: You can also avoid using `pixelIndex`, just keep a pointer to the current pixel and increment each loop

Comment: Also, just copy the code into 2 functions (at least your inner loop), one for 3 components per pixel and another for the other case, thereby avoiding the check for number of pixels per component.

Comment: the percentages are relative time spent, not total time spent--you should also time how long the entire loop takes to run. I have some profiler macros here that might help you: https://github.com/nielsbot/Profiler

Answer (score 2):

```
           const MAX_COLOR_DISTANCE_RSP = 1 / MAX_COLOR_DISTANCE;
           float attackForce = 1.0 - (colorDistance * MAX_COLOR_DISTANCE_RSP);
```

Also: [Neon Intrinsics](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0205g/BABFCGDJ.html) for high speed sqrt and recip estimates than can stepped to be more accurate as needed.  This replaces your distance sqrt.  Finally, do not use `powf`, use `val * val` as the compiler will probably not optimize that function into a simple mul for you.

You can also read your entire pixel with a single read (assuming 32-bit alignment which should be teh case with an RGBA file format):

```
uint32_t *sourceImage = (uint32_t *)(&sourceImage[pixelIndexIntoImage]);
uint8_t pixels[4];
*(uint32_t *)(&pixels[0]) = *sourceImage;
```

And now your array of pixel has all 4 components ready for reading, though you'll have to experiment slighly to figure out which pixel has which color due to endianess issues.  One 32-bit read is much faster than 3, 8-bit reads.

Also, all those global accesses may be hurting your cache.  Try placing them all in a single struct to make sure they are adjacent.  It will help the compiler with local pool management as well.

Comment: This is the kind of stuff I love poking around with.  I even get paid to do it at my current job which is a double bonus :)

Comment: MichaelDorgan @nielsbot, replacing division with multiplication indeed helped a little—thanks.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by "...placing them all in a single struct", could you elaborate. Also, i'm trying to get the assembly. cheers

Comment: I had assumed that all your definition vars were global.  Now that I re-read it, that may not be the case.  The tip gets at the fact that each individual global requires a bit of glue code.  Putting them all into a single struct takes that down to 1 value and relieves register spillage pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Turn that `1.0` into a `1.0f` and make sure `MAX_COLOR_DISTANCE` is defined as `<something>.0f`, otherwise there are a whole lot of implicit type conversions on your extremely expensive line.

The sort of division you're doing isn't particularly expensive; on ARM what's expensive is integer division because — believe it or not — there's no built-in integer division prior to the ARMv7s instruction set. Floating point division is a lot faster, at least if you stick to single precision.

Are there any extra constraints you're failing to mention? I notice your colour distance formula doesn't really correlate with how human's visually perceive colour.

On iOS, at least since 5, it'd also be an option to kick this out to the GPU since you're permitted direct access to texture buffers, removing the cost of passing data back and forth between OpenGL. Is that an option?

Comment: thanks for the "f" tip, i couldn't believe it shaved 25% off the total processing time. The color distance is used as a mathematical method to achieve the algorithm's goal and it indeed has no correlation to human's visually perceived color. Yet, if i can speed up that intensive inner loop, it would be a win.

Comment: This is an awesome tip and I should have seen it :)

Answer (score 1):

If the cycles really are being spent in the calculation of `attackForce`, you could precompute a table mapping `colorDistance` values to `attackForce` values and replace your division with a quantize operation and a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiplications:**

```
int pixelIndex = (col + row * width);
int pixelIndexIntoImage = pixelIndex * COMPONENTS_PER_PIXEL;
```

Can be changed into additions. That applies almost anywhere when using indices.

**Method calls:**

```
colorDistance = sqrtf( powf(redPixel-redNeigh, 2) + 
                                           powf(grnPixel-grnNeigh, 2) + 
                                           powf(bluPixel-bluNeigh, 2));
```

Don't use `powf` here. You can go simply with `(grnPixel-grnNeigh)*(grnPixel-grnNeigh)` It will still be faster. Why using floats when your arguments are integeres?

Comment: The compiler should optimize `powf(x,2)` into `x*x` on its own.

Comment: Not that I've seen, but many of the compilers I work with are not "great" :)

Comment: @StephenCanon Some would some wouldn't, even depending on compiler arguments. However the fact that `powf` is used implies that we are converting the integers into floats. And there is no need to do it until `sqrtf`.